# Duplicate key Endpoint exception while starting - in Spring Boot Admin Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I'm trying to configure Spring Boot Admin Client but i'm start the client application not able to register with Server. While starting of the application I'm getting the below exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key Endpoint(id=threaddump, url=http://localhost:9082/client-web/management/actuator/dump)

i'm using dependency version of client same version which I have used it for Spring Boot Admin Server

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the known bug in 'Spring boot admin 1.x'. But has been fixed in the later version (2.0.2).
*Endpoints* list is obtained from the AdminServerProperties class and defaults to

```
{
  "health", "env", "metrics", "httptrace:trace", 
 "httptrace","threaddump:dump","threaddump", "jolokia", "info",
 "logfile", "refresh", "flyway", 
 "liquibase", "heapdump", "loggers","auditevents"

    };
```

The problem with the duplicate key seems to be caused by the presence of both "httptrace:trace" and "httptrace" (and similarly for threaddump)

Overriding this in config by adding the line seems to solve the problem.

```
spring.boot.admin.probed-endpoints: [ "health", "env", "metrics", "httptrace:trace", "threaddump:dump", "jolokia", "info", "logfile", "refresh", "flyway", "liquibase", "heapdump", "loggers", "auditevents" ]
```

Pls see this for more: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/828

Alternatively, you can update pom.xml as below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2 or above</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After overriding the configuration I'm getting the below

Couldn't retrieve info for Instance(id=94f60734712b, version=2, registration=Registration(name=Application Web, managementUrl=http://localhost:9082/client-web/management/actuator, healthUrl=http://localhost:9082/client-web/management/actuator/health)}), buildVersion=null ..... ): 404

Comment: can you try using version 2.0.2 and above. if you are not bound to use 2.0.1

Comment: I'm getting the same in all the version

Comment: Now I allowed all the endpoints now in client side but now I'm another exception 
managementUrl=http://localhost:1501/APPNAME-web/=%2520/management/actuator,Connection refused: but now I'm getting another exception

Comment: org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "%25"

Comment: do this : @Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedPercentHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedPercent(true);
    return firewall;
}

Comment: After stopping the client, at server side I'm getting this issue o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Internal Server Error
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine - how can we resolve this issue